# How to get array values if checked or not one by one on a form?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, checkbox

I have a simple form, i would like to get all array values one by one and print on PHP. I'll be so happy if you help me.

```
<php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!isset($error)){
    try {

                if($_POST['mod_[1]']=="1"){
                    $mod_1 = '1';
                    $mod_1_symbol = "✓";
                }else{
                    $mod_1 = '0';
                    $mod_1_symbol = "X";
                }

                if($_POST['mod_[2]']=="1"){
                    $mod_2 = '1';
                    $mod_2_symbol = "✓";
                }else{
                    $mod_2 = '0';
                    $mod_2_symbol = "X";
                }

                if($_POST['mod_[3]']=="1"){
                    $mod_3 = '1';
                    $mod_3_symbol = "✓";
                }else{
                    $mod_3 = '0';
                    $mod_3_symbol = "X";
                }

                if($_POST['mod_[4]']=="1"){
                    $mod_4 = '1';
                    $mod_4_symbol = "✓";
                }else{
                    $mod_4 = '0';
                    $mod_4_symbol = "X";
                }

                if($_POST['mod_[5]']=="1"){
                    $mod_5 = '1';
                    $mod_5_symbol = "✓";
                }else{
                    $mod_5 = '0';
                    $mod_5_symbol = "X";
                }
}catch(PDOException $e) {
            $error[] = $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
}
?>

<form role="form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="contact-form">
<input type="checkbox" id="mod_1" name="mod_[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="mod_1" name="mod_[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="mod_1" name="mod_[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="mod_1" name="mod_[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="mod_1" name="mod_[]" value="1" />
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

i need to get some thing like this:
if mod_[1] checked write 1 else 0;

### if mod_[2] checked write 1 else 0;

Something like this.

Comment: $_POST['mod_'][2] =="1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop thru all checkboxes and check if checked

HTML:

```
<form role="form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="contact-form">
    <input type="checkbox" id="mod_1" name="mod_[0]" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="mod_1" name="mod_[1]" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="mod_1" name="mod_[2]" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="mod_1" name="mod_[3]" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="mod_1" name="mod_[4]" value="1" />
    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
for($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++){
    if($_POST['mod_'][$i]){
        echo ($i + 1) . ' Is checked';
    }
    else{
        echo ($i + 1) . ' Is not checked';
    }
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: The point is whic i did not select, it must show also that check boxes

Comment: Can you explain it a little more so I can try to help you?

Comment: There are 15 checkboxes. name mod_[]. So i would like to get value from each of them. For example if 1st one selected echo "1st selected", if second not selected echo "2nd not selected" .... it should go for these 15 checkboxes.

Comment: @ForzaDelLeone do you always know how many checkboxes you will have?

Comment: In form will be 15 checkboxes. That amount will never change but visitors can pick 3 of them or more or all.

Comment: @ForzaDelLeone I updated my answer, please have a look

Comment: They won't be set at all if they are not checked... but really People, let's use AJAX.

Comment: @StackSlave That's what he wants

Comment: Should be `if(isset($_POST['mod_'], $_POST['mod_'][$i]))`... but really use AJAX. Then you can just test an array you send as a JSON String.